# when i selected different type of projects. the following category always count again (repeat)vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i made a application which user can select different types of projects and any type of category of project(A,B,C). However i got a problem. When i click project 1, the category for example is A,B,C. But when i click project 2, it comes to A,B,C,A,B,C. What i need is no matter how many times i choose different project, the category will always be A,B,C. Not repeated again and again. Anyone help?

```
  Private Sub ProjectComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ProjectComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged
    'What project are we working with
    _selectedProjectId = CType(_projectInfo.Item(ProjectComboBox.SelectedIndex), BaseInfo).Id
    TypeContainer.Items.Add("A")

    TypeContainer.Items.Add("B")

    TypeContainer.Items.Add("C")

    TypeContainer.Items.Add("D")

End Sub
```

Comment: You seem to be adding `TypeContainer.Items.Add("A")` (along with `B`, `C`, & `D`) each time you change the selected index. That's your problem there, but how to fix it is hard without seeing the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you forgot to clear the items in the container. If you did not do so,
use `TypeContainer.Items.Clear`